# How to use group by with sum in criteria

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have 3 columns in my table id, uid and value. I want to sum the values of each uid. I know the query but i want to use criteria.

Query:

```
 SELECT uid,SUM(value) FROM post GROUP BY uid;
```

How can i use this in hibernate criteria?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Post.class);
cr.setProjection(Projections.sum("value"));
cr.setProjection(Projections.groupProperty("uid"));

Answer (score 0):

amount and employee is column name to use **SUM and GROUP BY**using ProjectionsList:-

    Criteria criteria=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(EmpAdvance.class);

        ProjectionList projectionList=Projections.projectionList();

    projectionList.add(Projections.sum("amount"));
    
    projectionList.add(Projections.groupProperty("employee"));
    
    criteria.setProjection(projectionList);